# merging multiple plotly plots and keeping interactivity

Tags: r, plotly

I have a plotly line chart with multiple groups. Each group is represented by a line and a color. As there are many groups, I only want to show some lines on default. The rest of the lines should be hidden by default, but the user should be able to make them visible by activating them through the legend.

I managed to create a plot that does exactely what I was describing. Unfortunately it take awefully redundant code to produce that plot, as I have to add each line seperately.

What I am looking for is a way to produce the same plot (keeping the interactivity) with less redundant code. I was thinking of `lapply` solution, but I don't know how I could merge the generated plots into one plot again.

Here is what I have done so far ... If anybody can give me a hint, I would appreciate it :)

```
# Init
"%>%" <- magrittr::"%>%"

# some data
dat <- dplyr::tibble(CAT=rep(LETTERS[1:3],each=10),
                     DATE=rep(1:10,length.out=30) %>%
                         lubridate::as_date(),
                     PCT=runif(30,min=0,max=1))

# transform tibble into list (by group)
dat_list <- dat %>%
    dplyr::group_by(CAT) %>%
    dplyr::group_split()

# plot data: what I am doing 
plotly::plot_ly(type="scatter",
                mode="line+marker") %>%
plotly::add_trace(data=dat %>%
                      dplyr::filter(CAT=="A"),
                  x=~DATE,
                  y=~PCT,
                  color=~CAT,
                  visible=TRUE)  %>%
    plotly::add_trace(data=dat %>%
                          dplyr::filter(CAT=="B"),
                      x=~DATE,
                      y=~PCT,
                      color=~CAT,
                      visible="legendonly")  %>%
    plotly::add_trace(data=dat %>%
                          dplyr::filter(CAT=="B"),
                      x=~DATE,
                      y=~PCT,
                      color=~CAT,
                      visible="legendonly") 
    
# plot data: what I want to do 
    lapply(dat_list, function(f){
        if (f$CAT=="A"){
            vis <- TRUE
        } else {
            vis <- "legendonly"
        }
        plotly::plot_ly(type="scatter",
                        mode="line+marker") %>%
        plotly::add_trace(data=f,
                          x=~DATE,
                          y=~PCT,
                          color=~CAT,
                          visible=vis)
    }) %>% 
    magic_merge_plots_function()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `magic_merge_plots_function`. It's nearly enough, if you put the initial `plot_ly` part outside of the `lapply`-function and add the traces to this plot.

Let's try this.

```
p <- plotly::plot_ly(type="scatter",
                     mode="line+marker")


lapply(dat_list, function(f) {
  
  vis <- ifelse(unique(f[, "CAT"]) == "A", TRUE, "legendonly")
  
  p <<- get("p") %>% 
    add_trace(p, data = f, 
              x = ~DATE,
              y = ~PCT,
              color = ~CAT,
              visible = vis)  
})
```

Comment: thanks works like a charm ... if something is that easy, there has to be some magic in it :D